Getting exception when running pygnnutils rtk_example.py
I have a Ublox ZED-F9P GPS module and am running the RTK_example.py script (renamed my_rtk.py) from the pygnssutils library with python3.8 on Linux aarch64, with RTCM corrections from AUSCORS NTRIP Broadcaster. The script runs fine for around a minute or so, then sometimes throws the following exception and stops -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/scripts/my_rtk.py", line 181, in <module>
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/scripts/gnssapp.py", line 176, in _read_loop
    main(**dict(arg.split("=") for arg in argv[1:]))
    self._send_data(ubr.datastream, sendqueue)
  File "/root/scripts/gnssapp.py", line 242, in _send_data
  File "/root/scripts/my_rtk.py", line 146, in main
    stream.write(raw_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 621, in write
    (_, parsed_data) = recv_queue.get(False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/queue.py", line 167, in get
    n = os.write(self.fd, d)
    raise Empty
_queue.Empty
TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)

The traceback refers to line 167 of queue.py, which is this -
165    with self.not_empty:
166             if not block:
167                 if not self._qsize():
168                     raise Empty

I have not made any changes to gnssapp.py or queue.py, and am reluctant to do so because they were written by smarter folks than me. I would appreciate suggestions on how to avoid the exception or ignore it (so the code keeps running). Many thanks

you did not provide the code that gave you this error.
